# problem with clothing in blender

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am experiencing a problem at frame 188. Something strange happens to the shirt, as if it is being pulled from something. I want the shirt to fall on the cube and remain in the same place. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello please share your file (only leave the cloth and cube): https://blend-exchange.com/